# Render HTML content in Ionic 3/4/5

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, ionic4, ionic5

**view.html**

`<div>{{text}}</div>`

The question is that 'text' has HTML that I wish to be displayed as it should but it only shows the HTML tags and text.

What can I do to render such content?

I've tried the earlier version (Ionic 1/2) solutions and nothing seems to work with Ionic v3.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You should use the `innerHTML` attribute binding like this:

```
<div [innerHTML]="text"></div>
```

Please take a look at the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation) for more information.

Comment: Edit: innerHTML works too - but fully non-capitalized does not.

Comment: it works for me in other case, : i had used Youtube API, which comes with encoded texts like &quote; . but this solution give me original symbol which exactly I want. Thanks bro,,,

Answer (score 0):

in case you want to write it in paragraph you can do that by

```
<p><span [innerHTML]="htmlObject"></span></p>
<p><span>"{{title}}" is the <i>interpolated</i> title.</span></p>
<p>"<span [innerHTML]="title"></span>" is the <i>property bound</i> title.</p>

<p><img src="{{heroImageUrl}}"> is the <i>interpolated</i> image.</p>
<p><img [src]="heroImageUrl"> is the <i>property bound</i> image.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**<div [innerHTML]="text">**

This solution works but some css not work in a html.
Like we got proper data from backend but not applicable into innerhtml .