# Ionic - InnerHTML alternative

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, innerhtml

I am have a variable which fetches a string from my database and displays it on one of my panels. The text which is fetched contains typical HTML tags such as `<b><u><p>` etc.

```
<div [innerHTML]="myVariableWithTags"></div>
```

This would work when tested with `ionic lab` but will not run on emulators or real devices.

So my question is what is an alternative of innerHTML for Ionic?

For example my variable `myVariableWithTags` is the following:

```
<b>This has to be bold</b> <i>and this italic</i>
```

I want to do the following:

```
<div> {{myVariableWithTags}} </div>
```

and would like to see the panel look like this:
**This has to be bold** *and this italic*

instead of `<b>This has to be bold</b> <i>and this italic</i>`

Is this possible?

Comment: i am not familiar with ionic but since this is simply angular you should avoid setting `innerHTML`. Usually you add innerHTML stuff like so: `<div>{myModelVariable}</div>` while `myModelVariable` is set inside the component and can contain anything. If you want to append HTML code and get this running you should explain the usecase better due to this is mostly a bad practice (not always avoidable but mostly)

Comment: @messerbill Basically if my string contains tags and I assign the content of the div as {{myVariableNameGoesHere}} the text will be displayed but the tags will not apply any effects - they will just appear as characters. I have edited the post above in order to provide a better example. Is this possible to be achieved in another way instead of `innerHTML`?

Comment: this looks better than the initial code....have a look here https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: check out `ngClass` which allows you to dynamically set `css` classes

Comment: @messerbill I am aware of `ngClass` however I do not believe this is what I need. I do not know what styles my string may have, so I cannot set them using `ngClass`. I just want to preserve whatever tags the string might have and display the text with the effects and styles. `[innerHTML]` does exactly this, but unfortunately Ionic does not support it.

Comment: So, you are basically saying that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44759927/1009922) does not work. Does it render the HTML tags as text in Ionic? Do you see an error message? Did you try with `[innerHtml]` (just in case)?

Comment: Have you tried just plain javascript? This isn't really a problem that Angular was designed to solve, not saying it can't solve it, but you do have the full power of js at your fingertips.

Comment: i'd strongly recommend **not** to make use of plain js in framework contexts as long as it is possible to solve using the framework

Comment: You could try give your `div` an **ID** and then you can access it from your Typescript over `document.getElementById("yourID")` then you can change your div content

Answer (score 5):

**step 1:** create a pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(html) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }
}
```

Step 2 : Declare and exports it on `app.module.ts`

```
import { SafePipe } from '........';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    SafePipe
    ],
    imports: [

    ],
    exports: [
        SafePipe
    ],
    providers: [
    ]
})
```

**step 3**: 
use `safe` pipe on html file

```
<div [innerHTML]="myVariableWithTags | safe"></div>
```

Comment: I have tried it just now. However, this did not work for me.

Answer (score 5):

InnerHTML Supported in IONIC-4 version

```
<ion-content padding>
    <div [innerHTML]="data"></div>
</ion-content>
```

**Don't use inside of `"<p>"` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `myVariableWithTags` in a `<span>`. This worked for me.